# +5 reputation notification, but when I look at my topic there's only +1 who gave me a reputation?

Tags: support

Basically when I post a Question like this one, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546229/how-do-i-print-a-users-input-with-double-quotes/43546288#43546288), the user that answered my question got +2 upvotes.

First question: Why do **I** get reputation when someone's answer gets a reputation?

Second question: My notification is telling me I got +5 reputation for the question I created, but why?

Comment: You got an upvote on your Q (+5) a downvote on your Q (-2) and you accepted an answer (gives the answerer +5, and you +2). Total +5 :)

Comment: @Patrice Accepting grants +15 to the answerer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't see it because you do not have enough rep but you have a up vote and down vote on your question.  That means you get +5 from the up vote and -2 from the down vote.

You also accepted the answer which gives you +2 rep.  You do not gain rep if the answer does otherwise.

So at the end you have +5 -2 +2 which gives you 5 rep.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I wish I could upvote answers but I have to wait until I get 15 reputation, sorry :)

Comment: @Crypto on meta votes don't change rep, so don't feel too bad.

Comment: @Patrice Oh, thanks again!

Comment: @Crypto No problem, glad to help.  Don't worry about not being able to vote.  If I cared I'd be doing this wrong ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the reputation breakdown here.

The notification is for the aggregated reputation you got since you last looked.

There is an upvote on your question (+5 rep), then a downvote on it (-2 rep), then you *accepted* the answer (+2 rep). Together - +5 rep.

Comment: Oh I see. I thought 1 upvote == +1 rep & 1 downvote == -1 rep :)

Thanks for the info!